# MongoDB bulk upload code

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo, bulkinsert

Following upload method is supposed to do bulk uploading to a given MongoDB collection. It runs successfully without exceptions but the data doesn't get reflected in the database. Not sure what is missing? @DanielRoseman

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo.database import Database
from pymongo.collection import Collection

def upload(host, port, db_str, collection_str, src_dir):
        # prepare connection to DB
        client = MongoClient(host, port)
        db = Database(client, db_str)
        collection = Collection(db, collection_str)

        # prepare bulk object
        bulk = collection.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()

        # iterate overall all data files and insert
        for datafile in datafiles(src_dir):
            try:
                data = json.load(open(datafile))
                bulk.insert(data)
            except ValueError:
                print "Upload failed for %s" % (datafile)
                continue
        bulk.execute()
```

Comment: Did you verify that `json.load(open(datafile))` returns the objects you expect it to return?

Comment: What does the BulkWriteResult() object returned by bulk.execute() look like ? Are there any non-zero entries ?

Comment: @Philipp yes. the objects are fine.

Comment: @JacodeGroot nInserted is equal to the docs I inserted. Following is the result {
   'nModified':0,
   'nUpserted':0,
   'nMatched':0,
   'writeErrors':[  ],
   'upserted':[  ],
   'writeConcernErrors':[  ],
   'nRemoved':0,
   'nInserted':100
}

Comment: @shane-reustle  Can anybody think of any other reason? is the issue related to some missing step which flushes out the data to DB?

Comment: Is the dataa uploaded to the correct db ? This could should work unless I am missing something.

Comment: @JacodeGroot you were right! there was a minor typo in the db name and MongoDB created that alongwith collection. :( if you post your comment as answer, I can mark it correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returned BulkWriteResult results show that the data is uploaded correctly into Mongo Db. Is the data uploaded to the correct database and collection ?

Comment: you are right! there was a minor typo in the db name and MongoDB created that alongwith the collection. :(